# Cannot boot Live CD on HP Pavilion

Tags: boot, hp

I need your help! I tried to boot Ubuntu from my Live CD but it's not working on my HP laptop (but it works on another Fujitsu laptop). Before it appeared booting, I got the messages from my camera

```
Could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14
error: variable 'root' isn't set.
```

After that, I got

- Stopping GPU interrupts balancing daemon

and loads of 'commands' (something I don't understand at all) then the screen goes black. It doesn't appear booting anymore. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Error might have occurred since the secure boot is not disabled in the BIOS.
Refer to the following link for installing ubuntu on a UEFI enabled computer
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI